# Bypass cloudflare and blazingfast browser check using a Shell Script on Centos7

Tags: centos, curl, browser

I am trying to find the way to bypass cloudflare and blazingfast redirection when I join to the website.

I want to bypass this restriction and download the html code from the target.

I found some information about pass cloudflare but still not working for me.

I tried to copy my cookie file from the xyz.com website that is protected with blazinfast and put the into cURL but not success..

I tried lynk browser but can not get the solution with this neither.

How could you bypass this restriction?

Comment: If you know the origin URL for the site, you can use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way cloudflare works is to act as a firewall between the site and the user. Obviously, this wouldn't work at all if there were a way to access the site directly. The main selling point of cloudflare is protection against ddos attacks, so if you can bypass cloudflare, that would defeat the entire point of using cloudflare, which is kind of obvious if you stop to think about it.

Basically, you have to check a few things, all of which means the site is not correctly configured:

See if you can find old records somewhere of its actual IP, the one cloudflare uses to access the site. If no such records exist, which they shouldn't, because if you use cloudflare, you should have changed the IP address to a new one that only cloudflare knows. So that would be misconfiguration one.

Second, you'd then try to access the site in question directly via its IP address, and if it had proper rewrite rules, any access that is not the domain name gets rewritten to its domain name, which means, it gets sent back around to the cloudflare firewall, which ends the story.

I don't know anything about blazingfast, but unless the site totally messed up their cloudflare setup, that alone should disable any possible direct connection to any file on the site via http/https.

Sometimes you can find old IP addresses for the site listed, but, again, if the site set up their cloudflare correctly, they changed the IP at the time of switching to cloudflare, to remove that chance detection.

On a technical level, the only reason anyone would want to do something like this is because they are precisely the person that cloudflare is being used to protect against.

Obviously, you can access any webpage html, by browser, but cloudflare does some other tricks that make it difficult if not impossible to download the actual site html with command line tools, due to some features that vary depending on the security level, and caching requirements, etc, of the cloudflare configurations. I had to, for example, whitelist the IPs for some wget type requests the site receives that are legitimate when it was passed through cloudflare, but you have to be the admin for the cloudflare account to do that.

If you're not talking bulk downloading of the site, you of course can just save the html source from a gui browser.

[checked, revised:] actually, I just tested, and wget grabbed the html from a cloudflare protected site fine, not sure though, since I might be whitelisted, can't remember. but worth a try, a recursive wget site download might work, hard to say, the only way to know  is to try. But with the extra layer of blazingfast, it would depend on what they do as well, what filters they run, etc, and what service levels the site has with that hosting company etc. However, repeated requests for pages may result in an IP block, the only way to know is to test it.

The raw wget output will also show you what happened in the request, response codes, etc, which can be useful information.

It sounds like blazingfast is using something similar to cloudflare's high security setting, which sets a cookie, and basically requires a gui browser, it's a throttle that relies on the working gui full browser, so normal users can access the site once their browser does what they expect a gui browser to do. My guess is any automated download attempt, even if you succeeded in your first few file grabs, would then trip an automated IP block.

Of course, what your question is really asking is how to bypass DDOS protection on a website, which is something a lot of annoyed site attackers would also like to know.

Comment: How did you use wget? Could you show me some example? I tried a simple browser made in vb.net and works nice with cloudflare, but not with blazingfast, so I would try with wget

Comment: to test any page, the simplest: wget -O- yoursite.com/page the -O - means, put output to stdout, not a file. That way you can just read it on the console. However, if you are using vb.net, that 'simple' browser is probably using some windows browser components, which just means it's emulating a normal browser, I assume, I know nothing about vb.net. I assume blazingfast does more aggressive checks, but do realize, nobody is actually going to solve this for you because you're trying to break ddos protection.

Comment: It does not require a GUI browser.  Cloudflare generates a algo to be hashed.. any javascript engine can process it without the browser.

Comment: Yes, but that raises the bar so high it's irrelevant for most users.